# WPF application framework IView issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, waf

I've developing WPF PRISM application and in that toolbar region i'm trying to inject its viewmodel using 'waf' framework classes below is the code snippet.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ToolbarViewModel : ViewModel<IToolbarView>
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public ToolbarViewModel(IUnityContainer container, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IToolbarView view)
        : base(view)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }
}
```

**IView:**

```
public interface IToolbarView:IView
{
}
```

**Designer code:**

```
public partial class ToolbarView : UserControl, IToolbarView
{
    public ToolbarView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But while compiling this code I'm getting below error, what could be the issue here?

> Error 1   The type 'MAMA.ApplicationModule.Controllers.IToolbarView'
>   cannot be used as type parameter 'TView' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Waf.Applications.ViewModel'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from
>   'MAMA.ApplicationModule.Controllers.IToolbarView' to
>   'System.Waf.Applications.IView'.  D:\MajorApps\SampleApp\MAMA.ApplicationModule\ViewModels\ToolbarViewModel.cs    13  18  MAMA.ApplicationModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compiler says that it cannot cast IToolbarView to IView. Maybe the IView type which the IToolbarView interface implements is not the System.Waf.Applications.IView type from the [WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com).

```
public interface IToolbarView : System.Waf.Applications.IView
{
}
```